# Hungriness chart - where to find?

Tags: user-research, charts, experience

So, I have a funny, border-UX question...

My friend will have a wedding soon. I'm the best man or whatever it's called - organizer.

We'll have some users called **guests**. Some will travel a long way (a few hours of commuting), while others will join us in the city.

Let's measure their satisfaction by **measuring how hungry they are**.

I guess we could measure it by **calories gained and calories burnt** (dancing, logistics, general decline while chatting).

I'm trying to build a kind of "**user journey**" and I'd like to see *where to place each course through the day*. For this, I'm trying to build a chart.

Questions:

- Where could I find charts of a "general day"?
- What is the scientific definition of hungriness, and where could I find it? What causes its symptoms? What's the easiest model for it?
- What else should be calculated in in order to make this model as simple as possible yet sufficient?

Hope this fits the format/topic of the site.

Comment: There are scientific definitions of calories needed for specific types of work, see for instance some [NASA docs](http://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section07.htm#7.2.2). However, I seriously doubt a wedding can be considered "a general day", unless you are forced to attend a string of them. For one thing, alcohol consumption is a major factor...

Answer (score 4):

Like pain, **hunger is entirely subjective** until you have measurable physical symptoms.

When I say I'm hungry, I haven't eaten in about a day and I *need* food.  When my girlfriend says she's hungry, it means thad she hasn't eaten for about 2-3 hours and feels like a snack.

So, to try and get around this a little, I would **present hunger in terms of something measurable**, like how much you could eat now.  You could also make this fun :)  I would suggest a scale of hunger with objects in a range stating

---

## I could eat:

## **1)** [image]  ... other objects ...    **5)** [image]

Comment: Thx :) I already have a male and a female persona. However, I'm thinking about having a timeline chart of 24 hours, with "I'm literally _starving_" and "I can't even _look_ at food" as edge cases for each. We'd likely serve main courses only after the effects of appetizers wore off a bit. I know this is a bit of "half-scientific", perhaps even pseudo-scientific, but that's the fun part, isn't it?:)

Comment: @Aadaam If everything were scientific there would be little fun in the world :)  Please me know how this works out.